# How often can I archive and unarchive persistent data in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a level based game and I need to keep track of two properties, even after the app is closed: cube essence, a Float, and high scores, a dictionary([Int : Float]). This is the class I created:

```
class PlayerData: NSObject, NSCoding {

// Properties
var cubeEssence : Float
var levelHighScore : [Int : Float]

//Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data")

struct PropertyKey {
    static let essence = "essence"
    static let highScore = "highScore"
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(cubeEssence, forKey : PropertyKey.essence)
    aCoder.encode(levelHighScore, forKey : PropertyKey.highScore)
}

init?(cubeEssence: Float, levelHighScore: [Int : Float]) {
    self.cubeEssence = cubeEssence
    self.levelHighScore = levelHighScore
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    var cubeEssence : Float = 0
    if let essence = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.essence) as? Float {
        cubeEssence = essence
    }

    var levelHighScore : [Int : Float] = [:]
    if let highScore = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.highScore) as? [Int : Float] {
        levelHighScore = highScore
    }

    self.init(cubeEssence : cubeEssence, levelHighScore : levelHighScore)
}
}
```

My original plan was simple: too load the PlayerData on the start of the app and to close it when the app is terminated. However, I have read that relying on applicationWillTerminate() method is not that reliable. So I was thinking of just unarchiving the old PlayerData object and archiving a new one every level. So it would go like this:

1. Player opens the app
2. PlayerData is unarchived and assigned to a variable
3. Player starts playing a level and gets a new high score or more cube essence
4. I unarchive the PlayerData (if there is one) and archive a new one, which contains the updated data. This would be done to always have only one PlayerData object.

Is this a good way of doing this? Is it too performance-heavy to archive and unarchive every time a player passes a level?

Comment: I'd say, test it for your particular app, if there are any performance issues, optimize. What works in one app may not work in another due to the size of the data you are archiving.

Comment: @paulvs is there any other way to archive instead of using an NSCoding object?

Comment: There is Core Data, plists, NSUserDefaults (not secure), serialize to JSON file, etc. See here for Core Data vs archiving: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: @paulvs what do you recommend the most for what I am trying to score (a float, and a dictionary)?

Comment: To be honest, it's very unlikely you'll ever have problems with unarchiving/archiving objects that contain scores (a `Float` and a `Dictionary<Int, Float>`).

Comment: @paulvs so you would recommend what I am doing right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146918/discussion-between-paulvs-and-pablo).